# tutorials about Tree Data structures with left,right and parent nodes

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree, nodes

Could someone direct me to some tutorial on Tree Data Structures using C **with left, right and parent Nodes** in structure. I've searched with Google and in Stack Overflow but I only find tree with only Node *left and Node *right.
To be clear, I'm searching for Tree tutorial with :

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *parent, *left, *right;  
};
```

Comment: What specifically do you want to learn about?  What kind of tree is this (general binary tree?  red/black?)

Comment: What about nodes that, for example, don't have a left node?  Or a parent?

Comment: It's about binary tree. The aim is to test what is the parent's values, so I need to add *parent in the node's structure. I've done it, I've got segmentation fault, I think I didn't really understand and I need tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow. And actually I don't think you could find any tutorials for this, as this is more like an algorithmics related question. As far as I recall CLR[1](http://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_algorithms.html?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&redir_esc=y) covered this topic a little.

This is an example of how an add might look like for such a tree. But I think CLR covers it way better than I can exemplify in a few lines of code.

```
int add(node **root, int value)
{
   node *var,*parent_node;
   var = malloc(sizeof(node));
   var->data = value;
   /* if the tree hasn't been initialised we do so now */
   if (*root == NULL)
   {
      var->parent = NULL;
      var->left = NULL;
      var->right = NULL;
      return 0;
   }
   /* we look for the future parent of our new node */
   parent_node = search(*root,value);
   /* if the value already exists we return -1 */
   if (parent_node->data == value)
       return 0;
   var->parent = parent_node;
   /* put the new node into position */
   if (parent_node->data > value)
       parent_node->left = var;
   else
       parent_node->right = var;
   return 0;
}
```

That search function could be any textbook search function for a binary tree, as the parent doesn't come in when you do a search. Though it should be mentioned that the average search will return NULL if the value is not found, so you might want to modify that as to return the "parent" of the NULL. Something like:

```
node *search(node *root, int value)
{
   node *var, *cursor;
   cursor = root;
   while(cursor->data != value)
   {
      if (cursor->data > value)
          var = cursor->left;
      else
          var = cursor->right;
      if (var == NULL)
          return cursor;
      cursor = var;
   }
   return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think This [tree structure](http://tree.phi-sci.com/download.html) covers all of your needs. First take a look at [tree.hh](http://tree.phi-sci.com/tree.hh), but is in c++.